# How to write this separately $ a = b \equiv c = 0\pmod f $?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I would like to know if I could write this
$$ a = b \equiv c = 0 \pmod f $$

without the "=" and "$\equiv$" in the same line, because my Prof doesn't like it.

This is my solution:

Let $c=0$ and $a = b$ than

$$ a  \equiv c \pmod f .$$

Can I write it like that, without loosing something on the way?

If you have a better idea, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to include the constant $c=0$? Is it not fine to write$$a=b\equiv0\pmod{f}$$

Comment: Good question, maybe i don't need it. The goal was to say 
$a=b≡0(modf) $ <-> $a=b≡0(modf)$

Comment: You just wrote the same thing twice?

Comment: Probably:() 
The problem is  i can' post my hole proof here, because if I do I will get a problem.
So to be clear I use a,b,c as parameter for something important and just want do know, how I can get the   "=" out of $a=b\equiv0\pmod{f}$ or $a=b\equiv c=0\pmod{f}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is fine, but I suggest to add a short explanation:
$$a=b\equiv c=d \pmod m\implies a\equiv d\pmod m$$
because the (modulo $m$) relation is reflexive and transitive.